# set consisting of an empty set

Tags: python

To get an empty set in python I use `{}` and it works.

I need to use the empty set as an element in a set.

But `{{}}` yields an error and `{set()}` too.

Is there a way?

Comment: Please use google before SO if the literals are somewhat unknown to you.

Comment: Do this simple experiment in the Python interpreter: `type({}) == type(set())`.

Answer (score 7):

The contents of sets (and the keys of dictionaries) can only be *immutable* values. That means that their contents can't change. If you're using a regular `set`, its contents can be changed with, for example, the `.add` and `.remove` methods, so it's not possible to put it inside another set.

Instead, you [need to use a `frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). It behaves the same as a `set` except that you can't change its contents after it is created.

```
print frozenset([ frozenset() ]) == frozenset([ frozenset() ]) # True
```

Comment: Note that only the inner set needs to be a `frozenset`. You can still use `{ frozenset() }` or (for Python versions that don't have set literals) `set([frozenset()])` without any problems.

Comment: They need to be hashable, not immutable. This happens to coincide for builtin types.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` makes an empty dict.  You cannot have keyless items inside of dicts.  You cannot create sets inside of sets because they are unhashable.